# Rails association for different user types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a user model and want to attach profile information to it specific to the gender.

Should I have a FemaleProfile & MaleProfile model in addition to the User model that holds the gender neutral data as illustrated below?

User model:

```
has_one :FemaleProfile
has_one :MaleProfile

Fields :Name, :Age
```

FemaleProfile model:

```
belongs_to :User

Fields :Name, :Age, :Dress_Color
```

MaleProfile model:

```
belongs_to :User

Fields :Name, :Age, :Tie_Color
```

What I don't understand if this is indeed correct is that a user has either a male or female profile yet the association has both types of profile associated with the User.

Is there an inverse polymorphic relationship? I have taken a look at STI but it does not allow fields exclusive to the inheriting models.

Comment: do they have the same number of "different" fields? and you'd just like to differentiate the labeling because of the gender?

Comment: no, the male user may have 4 extra unique fields while the female user has 2 extra unique fields.

Comment: Still, you are in the exact configuration of MTI, and if you don't want to implement this directly, there is a simple gem which simulate its behaviour : https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider in this cas using `Multi Table Inheritance`. I personally use the `citier` gem to implement this : http://inspiredpixel.net/citier/

Concretely, you would have a `User` table with the 4 common fields, and 2 inherited tables, each one with its own fields, which seems to be what you look for.

Comment: I believe it's single-table inheritance that solves this problem.

Comment: I think @SteveRoss is correct. Should be Single Table Inheritance.

Comment: STI may not be the solution.

Comment: @Steve Ross, I disagree, with STI every fields would be in the same table, not with MTI

Comment: In the case given, the problem is that the general case is a person, and the specialization between the male and female gender is (one would assume) fewer fields. I'm sure the example from the OP was a simplification for the purposes of the question. However, STI works where only a few fields change and you don't mind an extra field lying around; polymorphic is better where some encapsulated attributes are held in common and the rest change. I'm not saying MTI is wrong; just that there are already 2 Rails ways to solve these cases.

Comment: Ok then. I was first thinking to MTI because @Okyekyein was initially talking about 20 fields per gender. But  you're absolutely right if there is a few fields, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with polymorphic associations (why are you asking for an inverse polymorphic implementation?) or a serialized attribute.

**Serialized Attribute**

you can add a `gender_details` column with type text and then serialize this attribute.  then define female and male attributes.

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  MALE_DETAILS = %w[sports cars]
  FEMALE_DETAILS = %w[perfume flowers]

  serialize :gender_details, Hash

  (MALE_DETAILS + FEMALE_DETAILS).each do |attr|
    define_method attr do
      self.gender_details ||= {}
      self.gender_details[attr.to_sym]
    end

    define_method "#{attr}=" do |value|
      self.gender_details ||= {}
      self.gender_details[attr.to_sym] = value
    end
  end
end
```

so you can use

```
user.sports = 'Basketball'
user.flower = 'Rose'
```